# Angular Universal - routes are not being rendered

Tags: angular

**Progress Update**

If I change the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/gdp">` than the gdp page content appears but not the others. Still not sure how to resolve the issue.

**Original Post**

I am trying to prerender my application with angular universal. No routes are being rendered unfortunately except the home page of the website (i.e the first route the application is supposed to open). I've the following `angular.json`.

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "cli": {
        "analytics": false
    },
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "ourworldincrypto2": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                },
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                    "strict": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/ourworldincrypto2/browser",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets", "src/sitemap.xml"],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",

                            "./src/assets/vendors/owl/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css",
                            "./src/assets/vendors/owl/aos/dist/aos.css/aos.css",
                            "./src/assets/vendors/owl/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
                            "./src/assets/vendors/owl/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css",
                            "./src/assets/css/owl/style-owl.css",

                            "./src/assets/css/bootstrap-slider.min.css",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "./src/assets/js/jquery.color.js",
                            "./src/assets/js/bootstrap-slider.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",

                            "./src/assets/vendors/owl/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "5mb",
                                    "maximumError": "5mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
                        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": ["tsconfig.app.json", "tsconfig.spec.json", "e2e/tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.server.json"],
                        "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "deploy": {
                    "builder": "angular-cli-ghpages:deploy",
                    "options": {}
                },
                "server": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/ourworldincrypto2/server",
                        "main": "server.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "outputHashing": "media",
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "optimization": true
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve-ssr": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build",
                        "serverTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:server"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build:production",
                            "serverTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:server:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "prerender": {
                    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:build:production",
                        "serverTarget": "ourworldincrypto2:server:production",
                        "routes": [
                            "/",
                            "/gdp",
                            "/billionaires",
                            "/athletes",
                            "/cars",
                            "/houses",
                            "/snp500",
                            "/crypto",
                            "/wealthy",
                            "/nba",
                            "/pres-candidates",
                            "/btcppr"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "ourworldincrypto2"
}
```

Note that the main `index.html` is rendered successfully. The rest of the routes are not. The resulting content of one of the routes.

```
<body>
    <app-root _nghost-sc117="" ng-version="11.2.9">
        <router-outlet _ngcontent-sc117=""></router-outlet>
        <!---->
    </app-root>
    <script src="runtime.7b63b9fd40098a2e8207.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="scripts.e59b277616b2b3c913c8.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="main.8547f840d1e13bfbc738.js" defer=""></script>
</body>
```

The resulting content of the main `index.html`.

```
<body>
    <app-root _nghost-sc117="" ng-version="11.2.9">
        <router-outlet _ngcontent-sc117=""></router-outlet>
        <app-home _nghost-sc116="">
            <div _ngcontent-sc116="" class="container-scroller">
                <div _ngcontent-sc116="" class="main-panel">
                    <header _ngcontent-sc116="" id="header">
                        <div _ngcontent-sc116="" class="container">
                            <nav _ngcontent-sc116="" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
```

and so on...

The `prerender` command I'm using.

```
ng run website:prerender
```

I am not exactly sure, where the problem lies as the build is always successful.

**Console output on running pre-render**

```
> ourworldincrypto2@0.0.0 prerender /home/mywork/ourworldincrypto2
> ng run ourworldincrypto2:prerender

✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files               | Names         |      Size
main.8547f840d1e13bfbc738.js      | main          | 601.84 kB
styles.611a2c13e272c1600ee9.css   | styles        | 424.73 kB
scripts.e59b277616b2b3c913c8.js   | scripts       | 254.49 kB
polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js | polyfills     |  35.98 kB
runtime.7b63b9fd40098a2e8207.js   | runtime       |   1.45 kB

                                  | Initial Total |   1.29 MB

Build at: 2021-06-11T15:15:35.305Z - Hash: 3112fa892b3d16001d76 - Time: 30957ms

Warning: /home/mywork/ourworldincrypto2/src/app/services/helper.service.ts depends on 'millify'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies


✔ Server application bundle generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files | Names         |    Size
main.js             | main          | 3.85 MB

                    | Initial Total | 3.85 MB

Build at: 2021-06-11T15:15:37.487Z - Hash: d3637b1c658cbd8e1cae - Time: 28837ms
✔ Prerendering routes to /home/mywork/ourworldincrypto2/dist/ourworldincrypto2/browser complete.
```

**Routes File**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'gdp',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'billionaires',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'athletes',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'cars',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'houses',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'snp500',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'crypto',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'wealthy',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'nba',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'pres-candidates',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'btcppr',
    component: ComparisonsComponent,
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: When i use prerender, the console output shows any problem and which route are being generated, so, can you post the CLI output?

Comment: hi @Hoch, please check the update

Comment: can't see any error.. :/ So, check my routes and compare: https://pastebin.com/ncJHK6Rq

Comment: also published the routes file

Comment: They are the same component? Tip: lazy load the routes, so you will decrease the Initial Total of 3.85 MB. https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: yes the component uses the route path to distinguish the pages. Thanks for the suggestion.